# Converting Oracle SQL to TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following Oracle SQL:

```
    select a.t$orno || '|' || a.t$pono || '|' || a.t$item || '|' || ltrim(rtrim(c.t$dsca)) || '|' || 
a.t$suno || '|' || ltrim(rtrim(b.t$nama)) || '|' || 
a.t$pric || '|' || (a.t$dqua - a.t$iqan) || '|2401|' || a.t$comp || '|' || e.t$cuqp || '|' || e.t$cupp || '|' || (a.t$amnt - a.t$iamt) || '|' || e.t$pacn  || '|' || e.t$dim1  || '|' ||   e.t$dim2                                                             
    || '|' || a.t$reno  || '|' || a.t$srnb
    from baan.ttdpur045310 a, baan.ttccom020310 b, baan.ttiitm001310 c, baan.ttdpur041310 e
    where a.t$srnb > 0
    and   a.t$reno != 0
    and   a.t$dqua !=0
    and   (a.t$dqua - a.t$iqan) != 0
    and   a.t$suno = b.t$suno
    and   ((a.t$suno, a.t$orno, a.t$pono, a.t$srnb) not in (select d.t$suno, d.t$orno, d.t$pono, d.t$srnb from baan.ttdpur046310 d)
    OR ((a.t$suno, a.t$orno, a.t$pono, a.t$srnb) in (select d.t$suno, d.t$orno, d.t$pono, d.t$srnb from baan.ttdpur046310 d WHERE a.t$orno = d.t$orno and a.t$pono = d.t$pono and a.t$srnb = d.t$srnb and a.t$dqua != d.t$qana)))
    and   a.t$item = c.t$item
    and   a.t$orno = e.t$orno
    and   a.t$pono = e.t$pono
```

Here is my attempt to convert it to TSQL for microsoft sql server:

```
        select a.t$orno,a.t$pono,a.t$item,ltrim(rtrim(c.t$dsca)),a.t$suno,ltrim(rtrim(b.t$nama)),a.t$pric,(a.t$dqua - a.t$iqan),'2401',a.t$comp,e.t$cuqp,e.t$cupp,(a.t$amnt - a.t$iamt),e.t$pacn,e.t$dim1,e.t$dim2,a.t$reno,a.t$srnb
from    dbo.ttdpur045310 as a,      dbo.ttccom020310 as b, dbo.ttiitm001310 as c, dbo.ttdpur041310 as e
where a.t$srnb > 0
and   a.t$reno != 0
and   a.t$dqua !=0
and   (a.t$dqua - a.t$iqan) != 0
and   a.t$suno = b.t$suno

and   ((a.t$suno, a.t$orno, a.t$pono, a.t$srnb) not exists (select d.t$suno, d.t$orno, d.t$pono, d.t$srnb from dbo.ttdpur046310 as d)
OR ((a.t$suno, a.t$orno, a.t$pono, a.t$srnb) exists (select d.t$suno, d.t$orno, d.t$pono, d.t$srnb from dbo.ttdpur046310 as d WHERE a.t$orno = d.t$orno and a.t$pono = d.t$pono and a.t$srnb = d.t$srnb and a.t$dqua != d.t$qana)))

and   a.t$item = c.t$item
and   a.t$orno = e.t$orno
and   a.t$pono = e.t$pono
```

I am getting the following error:

> Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 33
> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','.
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 34
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'OR'.
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 34
> Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: replace the | with + signs

Comment: My main issue is with the OR statement in the WHERE clause

Comment: what is wrong with what u did? what exactly is the error/issue?

Comment: Change the multi-column in clause into an exists -clause.

Comment: Can you please help with the exists clause?

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you posted any errors you were getting, but I believe this should work:

```
    SELECT        A.T$ORNO, A.T$PONO, A.T$ITEM, LTRIM(RTRIM(C.T$DSCA)) AS T$DSCA, A.T$SUNO, LTRIM(RTRIM(B.T$NAMA)) AS T$NAMA, A.T$PRIC, A.T$DQUA, A.T$IQAN, A.T$DQUA - A.T$IQAN AS Expr1, '2401' AS Expr2, 
                         A.T$COMP, E.T$CUQP, E.T$CUPP, A.T$AMNT, A.T$IAMT, A.T$AMNT - A.T$IAMT AS Expr3, E.T$PACN, E.T$DIM1, E.T$DIM2, A.T$RENO, A.T$SRNB
 FROM dbo.TTDPUR045310 AS A
INNER JOIN dbo.TTIITM001310 AS C ON A.T$ITEM = C.T$ITEM
INNER JOIN dbo.TTCCOM020310 AS B ON A.T$SUNO = B.T$SUNO
INNER JOIN dbo.TTDPUR041310 AS E ON A.T$ORNO = E.T$ORNO
  AND A.T$PONO = E.T$PONO
 LEFT JOIN dbo.TTDPUR046310 AS d ON A.T$SUNO = d.T$SUNO
  AND A.T$ORNO = d.T$ORNO
  AND A.T$PONO = d.T$PONO
  AND A.T$SRNB = d.T$SRNB
WHERE A.T$SRNB > 0
  AND A.T$RENO <> 0
  AND A.T$DQUA <> 0
  AND (A.T$DQUA - A.T$IQAN) <> 0
  AND d.T$SUNO IS NULL;
```

Comment: This is actually the part that I am having trouble implementing from the original Oracle:

Comment: OR ((a.t$suno, a.t$orno, a.t$pono, a.t$srnb) in (select d.t$suno, d.t$orno, d.t$pono, d.t$srnb from baan.ttdpur046310 d WHERE a.t$orno = d.t$orno and a.t$pono = d.t$pono and a.t$srnb = d.t$srnb and a.t$dqua != d.t$qana)))

Comment: for every paren like this: (a.t$suno, a.t$orno, a.t$pono, a.t$srnb) replace with (a.t$suno+ a.t$orno+ a.t$pono+ a.t$srnb) ---- cast fields to varchar if needed